# Nodejs API code coverage based on actual production traffic

Tags: node.js, api, code-coverage, istanbul, dead-code

I'm working on a quite large nodejs code base which have been refactored and migrated from legacy to new service version several times and I highly suspect that some code is not used any more.

This dead code is still well tested, but I would like to get rid of it.

I had the idea to run 1 API server using [Istanbul](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul), put in in the production pool for some time (few minutes/hours/days) and see what code is actually useful (and identify probable dead code).

[According to its documentation](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul#the-cover-command), Istanbul cover can handle long-lived processes, so this seems not to be an issue.

**My concern is about memory overhead and potential slowness** due to the instrumentation of the code, and more globally **any thoughts, feedback and recommandation** about getting code coverage based on real traffic would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet to do what you want would be to run your app on 
[SmartOS](http://smartos.org/), [OmniOS](https://omnios.omniti.com/) or some other illumos/OpenSolaris distro and use [DTrace](http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/).

See:

- http://dtrace.org/blogs/about/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTrace
- https://wiki.smartos.org/display/DOC/DTrace

Comment: You can also dtrace node.js applications using FreeBSD 10.3 or above - Most hosting providers offer that. You will need to compile node.js with the `--with-dtrace` option